# lambda functions and list of functions in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I have an array of functions, for example:

```
>>> def f():
...     print "f"
... 
>>> def g():
...     print "g"
... 
>>> c=[f,g]
```

Then i try to create two lambda functions:

```
>>> i=0
>>> x=lambda: c[i]()
>>> i+=1
>>> y=lambda: c[i]()
```

And then, call them:

```
>>> x()
g
>>> y()
g
```

Why c[i] in lambda are the same?

Comment: The _easy_ way to solve this problem is to just not create the useless `lambda`s in the first place. Just replace those two lines with `x = c[i]` and `y = c[i]`, and you will get exactly the functions you wanted. The only reason to ever write `lambda: f()` instead of `f` is to stick `f` into a closure namespace to look it up later, instead of just using it. You don't want to do that here, and in fact that's exactly what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the lambda function is fetching the value of the global variable `i` at runtime:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> x=lambda z = i : c[z]() #assign the current value of `i` to a local variable inside lambda
>>> i+=1
>>> y =lambda z = i : c[z]()
>>> x()
f
>>> y()
g
```

A must read: 
[What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python)

Comment: Note: the accepted answer for the linked question shows how to make the desired name capture happen (see the `createAdder` function at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/25050.

Answer (score 3):

In Python closures don't capture actual values, but instead they capture namespaces. So when you use `i` inside your function it's actually looked up in the enclosing scope. And the value there has already changed.

You don't need all those `lambda`s and lists to see this.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...   print(x)
...
>>> x = 2
>>> def g():
...   print(x)
...
>>> g()
2
>>> f()
2
```